# Visual Studio 2017 Community, Xamarin, WatchOS. Unable to build the simplest of watch apps

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I just included the Xamarin features to my installation of VS Community 2017. I've updated everything I could.

Yet, I follow the process of adding a "Single View App (iOS)" and to that adding a "Blank App (watchOS)".

I then try and reference the Extension project from the main app. But every time I try, the reference to either the Watch App or Watch Extension from the main App has this warning/error:

> The project 'WatchOSApp.WatchOSExtension' cannot be referenced. The
>   referenced project is targeted to a different framework family
>   (Xamarin.WatchOS)

If I try and access the Interface.storyboard, I get the following message:

> Something went wrong
>   A WatchKit Extension project must reference this
>   Watch App project.
>   Actions
>   Update WatchKit Reference

Clicking on "Update WatchKit Reference" doesn't seem to do anything, even though there already IS a reference to the Watch App project from the WatchKit Extension project.

Any help from anyone would be greatly appreciated, as I can't even seem to build a "Hello World" app at the moment, and it seems that there's something fundamentally broken.

Comment: refer to Xamarin.iOS installation guide for windows [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Fahadsk. Yes, I saw that document, and followed it from top to bottom. Have had no issue connecting to the Mac, or reading the code. But Even a basic, blank iPhone/Watch app has an error/warning before I even start coding.

Comment: Have have set project reference to `Watch App`? see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/getting-started/project-references/) , also make sure `Bundle Identifiers` is set correctly in `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Yeah, followed that document. But I think it's actually quite out of date by the looks of it. For instance, the deployment target for the Projects, set in the Info.plist, is 3.2, not 8.2 as in the page you linked. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem too and found out that my problems had to do with bad references, ultimately caused by incorrect Microsoft documentation.

To figure it out, I started with this sample project which does compile and also lets me view the storyboard:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/watchOS/SimpleWatchConnectivity/

By using this, in combination with Microsoft's project references documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/get-started/project-references?tabs=windows) I was able to get everything working.

Ultimately, the project references documentation can be followed, except the following parts of the documentation are incorrect:

- The watch app should have `.watchkit` instead of `.watchkitapp` suffix
- The extension project should have `.watchkit.watchkitextension` suffix instead of just `.watchkitextension`

I have left feedback on the documentation with the same information contained in this post, so at some point the documentation may be fixed.

Comment: I've moved on from the project and left the watch accompanying app for the time being. So I can't verify this, but it sounds like you've got it working correctly. I'll be happy to mark this as the answer until such time I can verify this.